# Could Benjamin have had ten sons within a period of two years as mentioned in Genesis 46:21?

Tags: genesis, jacob, joseph

(KJV) Genesis 46:21

> 21 And the sons of Benjamin were Belah, and Becher, and Ashbel, Gera, and Naaman, Ehi, and Rosh, Muppim, and Huppim, and Ard.

Emphasis added

Benjamin is called a ***lad***(Gen 43:8)which seems to rule out any children at this point.

When they leave for Egypt within two years of the famine he has ***ten sons***

As Joseph reveals himself to his brothers(Gen 45:1) he unequivocal states that they should bring his father to Egypt immediately.

1) Could there be an intervening period between this time & the bringing in of Jacob to Egypt to have warranted Benjamin to have sired ten sons

2) Or could Benjamin have had sons while he was still called a ***lad***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the bible timeline Joseph was born around 1916BC & Benjamin in 1903BC which gives us a thirteen year gap

So when Jacob went to Egypt(Gen 46:26) at hundred & thirty years old,Joseph was thirty nine years old which makes Benjamin twenty six years.

Judah calls Benjamin a lad

(KJV) Genesis 43;8

> 8 And Judah said unto Israel his father, Send the ***lad*** with me, and we will arise and go;  that we may live, and not die, both we, and thou, and also our little ones.

This word ***lad*** seems to a have a wide semitic range,so Judah used it in reference to Benjamin who was the last born

Benjamin was old enough to have sired ten sons before they left for Egypt

Answer (score 0):

Never see what's translated as the gospel truth. In the NASB, the Hebrew word "naar" ([Strong's H5288](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5288.htm)) is translated (singular and plural cases) as follows: attendants (1), boy (19), boy's (1), boys (1), child (12), children (4), lad (36), lad's (2), lads (3), servant (34), servant's (1), servants (23), young (12), young man (33), young men (38), young people (1), youth (14), youths (2).

And who knows how many wives Benjamin had?
In 1 Chronicles 7:6, he had three sons and in 1 Chronicles 8:1,2, he had five. Even though there is some overlapping in the names of the sons, they're not the same everywhere. The hand of the theologians who wrote the Bible is clearly visible in this inattention to detail. Even today, they have to take off their shoes and socks to work with numbers over ten.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Chris. Your points about the meanings of that Hebrew word, and that several wives could have been involved, are pertinent. But making personal comments about your opinion, or making insulting comments is not what Hermeneutics is about. Do take the Tour (below) to see why this site is very different to most other sites dealing with the Bible.

Comment: To Chris? above, you read incorrectly, stating "Chronicles 7:6, he had three sons and in 1 Chronicles 8:1,2, he had five". What 7:6 actually says is "Three of Benjamin's sons". The wording makes it clear that in that section they are giving the lineage of 3 of his sons not all of his sons.